# Problem iterating values from a property file in ant?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I'm having issues in trying to iterate values defined in a property file. I'm trying to read jar files in a loop and copy them to a directory. The jar file names are defined in a property file. Here's my sample file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><project name="beehive" basedir=".">

<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>

<loadfile property="file.list" srcFile="test.txt">
    <!--<filterchain>
        <striplinebreaks/>
    </filterchain>-->
</loadfile>

<target name="testtarget">
    <for list="${file.list}" param="fileName">
        <sequential>
            <echo>@{fileName}</echo>
            <copy file="C:/Development/Doc/Build/@{fileName}" todir="C:/Development/Doc/Build/testdir">
            </copy>
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```

Here's the entry in test.txt.

wikihelp-1.0.0.jar

velocity-1.0.0.jar

I'm expecting that the for loop will read file name one at a time then perform the copy. Instead,its reading the 2 file names together and throwing the following exception :

Warning: Could not find file C:\Development\Doc\Build\wikihelp-1.0.0.jar velocity-1.0.0.jar to copy.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

- Thanks

Comment: Found the issue, adding **delimiter="${line.separator**} resolved it

Comment: You edited the solution into the question so it doesn't make sense any more.  In lists this looks like an unanswered question.  Why not put back the original code, then add an answer below, then accept it?

Comment: @martin clayton .. thanks for pointing it, I've made the changes and marked the question as answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue, adding **delimiter="${line.separator**} resolved it

In the for loop, I needed to add the delimeter for line seperator

```
<for list="${file.list}" param="fileName" delimiter="${line.separator}">
```